# I am trying to display different TableViewCells all at once

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to display 4 different TableViewCells in iOS swift at once. Luckily i had achieved that. The only problem I have is how to display them at the size adjusted in Storyboard. Instead, they are each being displayed at standard size (ie. small) on the simulator.

[Intended Display (Keep in mind that it is a demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/El68g.png)

I already found, then implemented, lines of code that helps me display multiple TableViewCells, which has worked so far.

```
    struct Storyboard {

    static let posterViewcont = "PosterViewCell"
    static let descriptionCell = "DescriptionCell"
    static let mapCell = "LocationCell"
    static let feedCont = "FeedCell"

}
```

and

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return 4
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    switch indexPath.row {

    case 0:
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Storyboard.posterViewcont, for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = "Insert Page View Controller Here!"
        return cell
    case 1:
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Storyboard.descriptionCell, for: indexPath) as! EventDescriptionCell
        cell.eventDesc.text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit er elit lamet, consectetaur cillium adipisicing pecu, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Nam liber te conscient to factor tum poen legum odioque civiuda."
        return cell
    case 2:
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Storyboard.mapCell, for: indexPath) as! LocationCell

        return cell
    case 3:
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Storyboard.feedCont, for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = "Insert Social Feed/Who's Going Here!"
        return cell
    default:
        return UITableViewCell()
    }

}
```

So far, I have tried to find a decent solution to displaying each cell at their intended sizes. But no luck
Let me know what I am (probably) doing wrong.

Comment: There is a [delegate function for row heights](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614998-tableview)

Answer (score 2):

All you need is to return different height for different cells, like what you are currently doing in `cellForRow` method

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
{
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        return 40
    }else if indexPath.row == 1 {
        return 60
    }else{
        return 80
    }
}
```

Comment: @Daniel Sure. Don't forget to mark it as correct answer and vote it up :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply add these two lines in the `viewDidLoad` function

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

Answer (score 0):

In viewDidLoad add these two lines

```
yourTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44
yourTableView.estimatedRowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

And do one of these things

From Storyboard
set no of lines of uilable to 0 and line break property to word wrap

**OR**

From code 
in cellForAtIndexPath

```
cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
cell.textLabel?.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
```

And remember to set bottom constraint of UILabel from cell(content view)